# Difference between "ps aux | grep httpd" and "systemctl status httpd"

Tags: systemd, ps

When I'm running command `ps aux | grep httpd` , it shows that `httpd` is in running state, but on running `systemctl status httpd` - it's inactive and disabled. Why is it so?

Comment: note that running `ps aux | grep httpd` will show the `grep` process itself, because its args match `httpd`.  Use either `ps -C httpd` or `ps aux | grep '[h]ttpd'`

Comment: You could be running a third party version of `httpd`. If you do `ps -C httpd -o etime,pid,args` does it show a path to the executable that matches the regular path?

Answer (score 3):

`httpd` is started manually by someone, out of control of the systemd service manager. This might be due to debugging purposes (ie. by starting `httpd` in the foreground).

From the manual:

> systemctl - Control the systemd system and service manager

The `ps` command only lists processed which are started and `systemctl` lists which services are known and can be managed by systemd.

From the manual:

> ps - report a snapshot of the current processes.